# Where can I find german patent examination?

Tags: examination, german, exchange

I know that for a US patent I have to go on public pair to check the exchange between the patent examiner and patent attorney or inventor. But I'm looking for the same data for a german patent. I think it should be on espacenet, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

At the depatisnet register. https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/Uebersicht?lang=en Search for the patent number then you can find the documents.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, it seems to be not public.

Comment: I'm happy to hear you found an answer! May I ask where you found that documented? It would be useful to include a brief citation so future visitors with your same question can read more into the answer.

Comment: DPMA (Deutches Patent- und Markenamnt) register is the "equivelant" of public pair. I haven't used it much, but I consider it user friendly. Select "file inspection" for the examination documents.